# SendInput, #u Does Not Trigger Across Script

Tags: autohotkey

I have a AHK instance that has `#U` as a hotkey trigger for a series of actions. It works correctly in this script.

But when I set up a separate AHK script to press that hotkey, it launches the Windows 10 hotkey for settings instead, even when I run it as Administrator. Other hotkeys also fail across scripts

My goal is to have a separate AHK script run to press that hotkey when as I need it scheduled.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

Script1.ahk:

```
#MenuMaskKey vk07

#a:: SendInput b
```

Script2.ahk:

```
#MenuMaskKey vk07

#InputLevel 1
$Numpad0:: SendInput {LWin down}a{LWin Up}  ; sends b, because of script1

#InputLevel 0   ; reset #InputLevel to default
```

For details read in the manual about the [#InputLevel](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InputLevel.htm) directive.

Comment: Using InputLevel at any level does the same thing... but using SendLevel seems to work but it also pops open the windows key (the # hotkey)... so close...

Comment: Ah ok, it seems Send is much more # friendly than SendLevel.

Comment: I guess windows really doesn't like the # button. It keeps triggering it as well as the hotkey.

Comment: It seems to hold down whatever button (# ! etc) even if I specifically tell it to release the button after.

Comment: Here is the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408603/ahk-across-script-in-windows-holds-down-the-button-even-when-instructed-to-relea).

Comment: Try my edited answer with [#MenuMaskKey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MenuMaskKey.htm) (works on my system).

Comment: The Inputlevel thing doesn't work at all for me at all, but I tried with the SendLevel and it still does the same thing. Seems the windows 10 system likes to hold down windows key in the background when it goes from script to script. [I made a new question at this point so you can see where I'm at now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408603/ahk-across-script-in-windows-holds-down-the-button-even-when-instructed-to-relea).