# AHK Across Script in Windows Holds Down the Button Even When Instructed to Release

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I have a hotkey program in a different script that I am trying to trigger (#u::) and it seems to have a buggy behavior.

Script #1:

```
#MenuMaskKey vk07
#u::
msgbox,,test
return
```

Script # 2 that is trying to trigger the #u:: hotkey:

```
#SingleInstance
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#MenuMaskKey vk07
SendLevel, 10
Send, #{u} ; This successfully triggers the hotkey but now it holds down the # button

sleep, 1000
Send, {RWin Up} ;Here I am trying to release it but it still doesn't let it go
```

Btw, this occurs with all other modifiers, too like shift, alt, and control.

I am on the latest version (v1.1.26.01).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Script #1:

```
#InstallKeybdHook
#UseHook
#MenuMaskKey vk07

#u:: msgbox, test
```

Script # 2 that is trying to trigger the #u:: hotkey:

```
#SingleInstance
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#MenuMaskKey vk07

SendLevel 1
SendInput, {LWin down}u{LWin Up} 
If GetKeyState("LWin")
    Send {LWin Up} 
If GetKeyState("RWin")
    Send {RWin Up}
```

Comment: SendInput, {LWin Down}u{LWin Up} did it! The rest was unnecessary.